# Changing root directory and forcing https

Tags: laravel, ssl, https, root

I'm trying to change root directory of my Laravel application and fore https all over website.
This is my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Point to public folder
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

    # Force https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

It changes root directory, but it doesn't force https. If I do it another way, first forcing https then set to root directory, then I get too many redirects

**EDIT** 
Solution was to change settings in my Cloudflare .  Cloudflare -> 'Crypto' tab -> SSL to 'Strict'

Comment: Solution was to change settings in my Cloudflare .  Cloudflare -> 'Crypto' tab -> SSL to 'Strict'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to change settings in my Cloudflare . Cloudflare -> 'Crypto' tab -> SSL to 'Strict'